# C: why int[] array is not allowed in C or C++

Tags: c, arrays

```
int main() {
    int[3] arr = { 11, 22, 33 }; 
}
```

Error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘[’ token

As far as I remember, this was allowed in C to declare an array either with "int[3] arr" (NOT OK) or "int arr[3]" (OK). I tried to find a reason but to no avail. I will appreciate any insight.

Used gcc version: gcc (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.1) 5.4.0 20160609

Comment: Because it isn't. Use `int arr[3]` instead. What you remember is true for Java... or some other language whose name *starts with **C***

Comment: Dimensions are always mentioned _after_ variable name in C and C++. This has *always* been the way it works.

Comment: Because that's neither C nor C++ and never has been! You could as ask well why `var a: pointer to integer;` is not allowed.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because most questions asking why a particular language was not designed with support for a particular syntax notation are ultimately futile and uninformative.  "Because the designers didn't decide to do it that way" is often the best answer available.

Answer (score 3):

The syntax `int[3] arr = { 11, 22, 33 };` is actually used in the D programming language, but is a syntax error in both C and C++.

It would be possible to extend the C syntax to allow this alternate syntax, but I don't know of a proposal to this respect.

Note also that a similar syntax is used since C99 for this:

```
printf("An array of 3 ints has a size of %zu bytes\n", sizeof(int[3]));
```

The C syntax to define this array is:

```
int arr[3] = { 11, 22, 33 };
```

Note that if you want to be non-conventional, you can use this syntax to access array elements:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    printf("arr[%d] = %d\n", i, i[arr]);
}
```